# Using Cloudberry SQL Server backup and Amazon Glacier efficiently

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier, cloudberry

I'm using Cloudberry Serverbackup to backup my SQL databases once a month to Amazon Glacier.

I know that just getting an inventory from Glacier can take a long time.

Is there a way that when the backup is being performed, that I can "save the inventory" so, that in the future should I need to get a backup from glacier I don't have to wait 5 hours just to get a list of the files?

Comment: I have discussed your issue with our developers.
Unfortunately, they wasn't able to suggest any workaround.
Only thing we can advise in such situation is to use Amazon S3 instead of Glacier. If you have any other questions or issues regarding CloudBerry software, don't hesitate to contact us directly at `ticket@cloudberrylab.com` Thanks, Vlad, CloudBerryLab Team